# Who this large blue droid seen behind Anakin Skywalker in Episode 1?

Tags: star-wars, droids, object-identification

I want to know the name of this large blue droid seen standing behind Anakin Skywalker during *Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace*

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a coffee maker

Answer (score 26):

According to the [*Ultimate Star Wars*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) factbook, that droid (an [R1-series shopkeeping drone](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R1-type_shopkeeping_drone)) helps to run Watto's shop. It doesn't appear to have a canonical name.

> *"An **R1 Type shopkeeping drone** handles most of the routine business operations, while Watto's slave, Anakin, repairs and cleans machinery, allowing Watto to dedicate more time to his gambling interests"*

[image]

Comment: Interesting that it appears to have Yoda-ears.  I wonder if this was a subtle reference by the designers?